# PHP Validating the File Upload

Tags: php, image, upload

I'm a PHP beginner and currently learning the "Validating the File Upload" part.

I made a test.php page containing following code:

```
var_dump(@$_FILES['file']['type']);
```

First, I uploaded an image "img.gif" and it returned:

```
string 'image/gif' (length=9)
```

Then, I changed the image's extension to ".jpg" and it returned:

```
string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
```

So I realized $_FILES["file"]["type"] only return the uploaded file extension but didn't actually check what file is it.

In this page, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp, there is a code:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
```

I'm wondering why above codes check file extension twice? I deleted some from above codes and this is my new code:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
```

Is my code correct? Or do you have any better ways to validate the upload file is a image?

Thanks!

Comment: Why my post got downvote? I just wanna make sure $_FILES["file"]["type"] is not necessay in the w3schools's codes

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could pass the `tmp_name` of the file to [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/function.getimagesize.php), it will give you the size and type of the image (if the first few bytes of that file appears to belong to an image). Otherwise it returns false, that will allow you to validate.

Besides, you MUST check the **extension,** of the original filename, because your web-server will judge your file by it, and execute accordingly. And of course a PHP file can fake a few bytes at the top, disguising itself as an image.

For example:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
    {
        // get the ext
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        // get the type
        $tmpfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $imagesizedata = getimagesize($file);

        if (!in_array($ext, $allowed)) { // check the ext
            //not an image
        } elseif ($imagesizedata === FALSE) // check the type
             //not an image
        } else {
            //image
            //use $imagesizedata to get extra info
        }
    }
}
```

For the error values see [file upload errors explained](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) at [php.net](http://www.php.net/).

Comment: thanks for mentioning getimagesize function

Comment: Please note that it does check if it's an image, but that doesn't mean it isn't an image that has been tempered with, see: http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/13/php-code-injection-a-simple-virus-written-in-php-and-carried-in-a-jpeg-image/ I recommend recreating the image using functions such as imagecreatefromstring and converting it to e.g. png. –  Arie 50 mins ago

Comment: From <a href="http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php">getimagesize()</a> PHP docs: `Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image.`

Answer (score 4):

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
```

This is checked twice because, the extension of the file and 'file type' can be differ, so someone can not upload executable file with .png extension.

In your modified code, it is possible to upload a different type of file with modified extension. like they can upload word document with '.png' extension.

Your new code is just checking extension and don't have double check.

Comment: I uploaded an exe file with png extension, the page returned:string 'image/png' (length=9)

Answer (score 0):

Your new code only checks the extension of the file and the size of the file. It doesn't checks the type of the file.

I will strongly recommend to use your old code because there it checks the file type also.

Comment: var_dump(@$_FILES['file']['type']) returned string 'image/png' (length=9) for an exe file but with a png extension, so it didn't check the file type but only the extension.