# Correct way to check if image is in fact an image

Tags: php

I am wondering what is the correct way to check if a user provided image is an actual image.

I saw the following two examples:

`$x = pathinfo('upload.png', PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Result: `png`

```
$x = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$x->file('upload.png');
```

Result: `image/png`

Comment: Try to resize it or use [getimagesize](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595592/php-validating-the-file-upload

Comment: `getimagesize`  ....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408125/php-check-if-file-is-an-image and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755192/uploaded-file-type-check-by-php might help

Comment: you could use the binary `file` (only available on *nix), but using `finfo` is also a very good way (maybe the best) to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The latter, an extension can be changed, finfo can be faked as well, but it is more difficult. See [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) for other ways to check. As [a commenter warns](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php#75275),  it is 'not that hard to wrap harmful executable code in a file identified as a GIF'. But that being said, here;s the image check I use:

```
if (!$img = @imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfilename)) {
  trigger_error('Not a GIF image!',E_USER_WARNING);
  // do necessary stuff
}
```

Good luck!