# PHP Upload error - File too large?

Tags: upload

Hi I'm trying to create a upload button that sends the file to my email along with a form, I made.

so far I have (below)

even tho I upload only a very small (35kb) file I get this error.

this paragraph has no further value to my query but the editor won't allow me to post this unless I type more stuff. so please ignore the hell out of this paragraph.Thank you

```css
#upload {
    width: 91%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#fileToUpload {
    width: 48%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#fileToUpload:hover {
    font-size: 16px;
 font-weight:normal;
}
```

```html
<?php
    $target_dir = "/uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
 
 // Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 31457280 ) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large. Please up to 3MB only.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "pdf" && $imageFileType != "cdr" && $imageFileType != "ai" && $imageFileType != "psd" && $imageFileType != "eps" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only vector images are allowed. Please only upload pdf, eps, cdr(X6), ai, psd or png files.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
 
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Select image to upload:
   <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
  </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

[image: my output]

Comment: after The upload files size error is fixed can someone please help me how to send these files to an email address

Comment: Don't rely on checking the mimetype to validate it's an image.

Comment: See here to correctly check for images http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595592/php-validating-the-file-upload