# How can I validate image saved with file_put_contents()?

Tags: php, security, xss, file-put-contents

I am using `file_put_contents($path, $image);` to save an image which a user will upload through a plugin (slimimagecropper.com FYI).

I'm concerned about XSS. What is the best way to check `$image` for XSS before saving it with `file_put_contents()`?

Comment: You should first check if the filetype is an image, and save it with an image extension. How do people upload `$image`?

Comment: Thanks. They will upload it through the plugin (slimimagecropper.com) which looks at the $_FILES array to get the image. As far as I can see, this plugin doesn't do any XSS checks server side, hence why I want to modify the plugin code where it writes `file_put_contents()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: [PHP Validating the File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595592/php-validating-the-file-upload)

To validate if the content is an image, you should validate:

- Its extension
  To prevent a remote file upload such as .php
- Its mime type
  Extra check to validate its file type
- Its content
  Preventing uploading text as image and similar

Try using this code (Taken from the reference) to validate the extension and mime type:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
```

And this code to validate its content (Taken from reference as well):

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
if (file_exists($file)) {
    $imagesizedata = getimagesize($file);
    if ($imagesizedata === FALSE) {
        //not image
    } else {
        //image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things you can do to sanitise the user upload. Everything in `$_FILES` can be manipulated, so don't trust it **at all**.

**Filename:**

Never trust the filename given to you by the user - always save it as a different and sanitised input. `image.jpg.php` -> `uniquestring_programatically_generated.jpg`.

**Getimagesize:**

Use the method `getimagesize($filename)` to verify it's an actual image, and it has a size.