# make validation for upload picture only (php)

Tags: php, html

I have 2 questions.

my first question--
I am using a HTML form to upload image files. Now i am using validation to allow the file types.
When i was searched through google i found this.

But when I change with "all file" When selecting a picture, Users can send data that is not an image.
My question is here, How to make validation for upload only image and big file below 2mb

my second question--
How to validate when people don't fill the file, I've tried this "!isset($picture))"
But it doesn't work.

[code]-->start

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<?php

require_once "db.php";
require_once "function.php";



if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){

  $name     = $_POST['name'];
  $info     = $_POST['info'];
  $picture  = $_FILES['picture'];


  if(!empty(trim($name)) && !empty(trim($info)) ) {

        if(add_data($name, $info, $picture)) {
      echo "success";
    }else{
      echo "fail";
    }

  }else{
    echo 'The data is empty';
  }
}


?>

</head>

<body>


<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Info</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><textarea name="info"></textarea></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>picture</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="file" accept="image/*"  name="picture"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><button type="submit" name="submit">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[/code]-->end

[code]function-->start

```
<?php

function add_data($name, $info, $picture){
global $connect;



$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $name);
$info = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $info);


$filePath = "file/".basename($picture["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($picture["tmp_name"], $filePath);


$query = "INSERT INTO try (name, info, picture) VALUES ('$name', '$info', '$filePath')";

if( mysqli_query($connect, $query) ){

      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
}
}
?>
```

[/code]-->end

Comment: Why have you tagged this java? Please edit your question and remove tags which do not pertain to the question

Comment: sory, i was ctrl+c and v. my bad

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595592/php-validating-the-file-upload#answer-15595623

Comment: I'm a php beginner, Still don't understand.